# Make only one bar in bar chart stacked?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

Is there any way I can create a bar chart based on data but make only one bar stacked? Like this (see the last bar):

[image]

I made this image by adding a shape to the last bar. Is it possible to create a chart like this natively in Excel, just using data in your sheet?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

1. Insert the value to stack in a separate column, using `0` for those columns where you don't want to stack anything.

[image]

2. Insert a stacked column chart:

[image]